# base32 decode to UTF in java

Tags: java, base64, decode, encode, base32

I want to decode a string to UTF-8 format in java. In the following code, I am able to get the expected decoded value from `String` decoded.

```
String s = "SFSFSFSFSF";
Base32 codec = new Base32();
String encoded = codec.encodeAsString(s.toUpperCase().getBytes());
Charset UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
String decoded =new String(codec.decode(encoded),UTF_8); // SFSFSFSFSF
String decoded2 = codec.decode(encoded); // [B@133314b
```

However, in my implementation specifically, I want to get the decoded val "`SFSFSFSFSF`" just by saying `codec.decode(encoded)` which is demonstrated in `String` `decoded2` in the code. I want to know how I can achieve this by changing the way the `String` is encoded.

Comment: It looks like the version of Base32 you're using returns a `byte[]`, not a `String`, from `decode`.  There's no better way to turn a `byte[]` into a `String` than the one you do in `String decoded`.